# Debugger displaying "some" instead of memory address

Tags: swift

I have a method that creates an object an returns it as usual.

```
func myFunction() -> MyObject?{
    var object = MyObject()
```

debugging it I can see that at the end of this function this object has a valid memory address.

```
    return object
}
```

However when I receive it instead of displaying nil or the object address I can see the word "some". If I compare this object with nil it is not evaluated as a non nil object.

```
result = something.myFunction()
if result != nil {
     println("never reaches here")
}
```

what is going on?

[image: debug answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared that method to return an *optional* `MyObject`. In Swift, optionals are implemented as an enum that has two possible values: `.None`, which is usually seen in its literal form, `nil`, and `.Some`, which holds the value of the optional as an associated value. You're seeing `Some` in the debugger because your method successfully returns a value wrapped in an optional.

You can [read more about Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496) in the Swift language guide.